# Avoid adding custom CSS to a node editing form?

Tags: theming

Situation

- custom module adding styles
- don't add styles to node editing form

How to avoid adding the style to the editing forms?

```
function crossfade_page_attachments(array &$page) {
  $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'crossfade/crossfade';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently discovered answer derived from the metatag module)

```
function crossfade_page_attachments(array &$page) {
  if (\Drupal::service('router.admin_context')->isAdminRoute()) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'crossfade/crossfade';
}
```